# SSL application load balancer on AWS WITHOUT a custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

Is it possible to give a application load balancer on AWS a SSL certificate, allowing allowing only HTTPS connections, if I don't want to use a custom domain?

Currently developing some internal dashboard applications, so have no need/want for a domain name attached to them.

I can only dig up info and tutorials of creating to a certificate in Cloudformation, when wanting to add a domain forwarding to the LB.

Comment: So what domain would the ssl certificate be issued against?

Comment: What's missing, is "how do you access the dashboard." If you intend to do something like https://foo.com/dashboard, for example, you would rely on the load balancer and/or reverse proxy at foo.com to do the correct routing. If you intend to use a non standard domain, managed by local dns like https://dash.foo.local you'd have to install, use, and manage self signed certs.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.

It's not generally kosher to issue an SSL certificate to an IP address, and since all `*.compute.amazonaws.com` style DNS names are floating and could be reassigned at any moment, they damn well won't issue one for them either. (Same stands for Let's Encrypt, by the way: you have to have a DNS name not issued by a provider.)

Just give your internal service a DNS name, be it something like `mydashboard.internal.mycompany.com` or whatever; it'll be easier to access, too.

Comment: _they damn well won't issue one for them either_ Is that also the case with precise, default DNS name of Elastic Load Balancer, like `<something>.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com`?

Answer (score 0):

The SSL certificate has to have a valid DNS name associated with it in order to work.  You need to request a certificate via ACM and then attach that to the ELB.  You can configure the ELB to only have an HTTPS listener to force secure communication.